# Python SQLAlchemy mocking

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

this is a method that I made chained DB query calls.

```py
import math
def get_all_keys():
    db_session = DBSession()
    keys = db_session.query(SomeClass).all()
```

I should mock `DBSession().query(SomeClass).all()`. I tried some but nothing worked. Here are my trials.

```py
@patch('app.modules.somemodule.DBSession')
def test_asd(self, DBSession):
    DBSession.execute.query.execute.all.return_value = [1, 2, 3]
    self.assertListEqual(DBSession.query('qwe').all(), [1, 2, 3])
```

In this attempt if I try to print `DBSession()` I get a `MagicMock` object which seems fine. But when I run `pytest` I got following error.

```
    self = <test_some_module.SomeModuleTests testMethod=test_asd>, DBSession = <MagicMock name='DBSession' id='140028663111976'>

    @patch('app.modules.somemodule.DBSession')
    def test_asd(self, DBSession):
        DBSession.execute.query.execute.all.return_value = [1, 2, 3]
        print(DBSession().query('qwe').all())
>       self.assertListEqual(DBSession.query('qwe').all(), [1, 2, 3])
E       AssertionError: First sequence is not a list: <MagicMock name='DBSession.query().all()' id='140028662649184'>

tests/test_some_module.py:21: AssertionError
```

Seems like I did something wrong while mocking. What is my mistake? I checked the documentation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're simply mocking the wrong thing, and asserting that the chain of calls should return an actual list with given items, not a magic mock object. Instead of `execute`, which would simply mock access to the attribute of the same name, you should be using the [`return_value`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value), as you've done in the final step. Given the chain

```
DBSession().query(...).all()
```

you should be mocking

```
DBSession.return_value.query.return_value.all.return_value = [1, 2, 3]
```

On the other hand in `test_asd()` in the assertion you're doing

```
DBSession.query(...).all()
```

so

```
DBSession.query.return_value.all.return_value = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 7):

You may use the alchemy mock for mocking session and data for SQLAlchemy

```
from alchemy_mock.mocking import UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock
db_session = UnifiedAlchemyMagicMock()
db_session.query.return_value.all.return_value = [1,2,3]

mock_res = test_asd(db_session)
self.assertEqual(mock_res, [1,2,3])
```

optionally you may also mock data by

```
db_session.add(SomeClass(column1=1, column2=2, column3=3))
```

Comment: now you may use [mock-alchemy](https://pypi.org/project/mock-alchemy/)